# Gridview data update on each textbox keystoke

Tags: .net

Gridview data update on each textbox keystoke

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear what you'd like to do, but assuming you want to update a running total or other such scriptable update:

1. Create a Javascript function to do the totaling from the controls.  This will require some processing of the ASP.Net control names.

   function UpdateTotal(txtYourTextBoxId)
   {
       // Get the value from the textbox, in this case a Quantity
       var Qty = document.getElementById(txtYourTextBoxId).value;

   ```
   // Do stuff with this control and/or all controls on page
   // foreach, etc.


   // change the total at the bottom of the grid
   document.getElementById("ctl00_lblTotal").innerHTML = Qty;
   ```

   }
2. In your code behind, add an "OnChange" attribute whenever the textbox value changes.  This is done in the RowDataBound event:

   protected void myGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;
       TextBox txtYourTextBox= (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtYourTextBox");
       txtYourTextBox.Attributes["onchange"] = "UpdateTotal(this.id)";
   }

Thus whenever there is an OnChange event from a textbox, the javascript function is fired.